# What happen if I accidentally connected HDMI with 2 GPU

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, gpu

I was trying to change my monitor display to the other desktop earlier, but instead of unplugging the HDMI from my other PC's GPU, I did a stupid mistake that I unplugged it from my monitor and powered on the other PC, causing 2 powered on GPU connected directly, will that cause damage or anything to my GPUs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't be a problem. Doing that is useless as you said, a mistake, it won't give you any functionality,  but no damage should be expected. In any case you can just check that both graphic cards keep working perfectly.